# Cannot disable network time control (NTP)

Tags: ntp, ntpd, wireshark

I want to analyze some protocols (ARP, NDP, etc.) inside virtualbox (OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa) using wireshark and tried to disable the "network time control"-synchronization.

```
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp off && timedatectl status 
                      Local time: Fri 2019-04-12 09:59:28 CEST
                  Universal time: Fri 2019-04-12 07:59:28 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2019-04-12 07:59:29
                       Time zone: Europe/Vienna (CEST, +0200)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: no
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Still, wireshark captures frequently NTP traffic.
I am aware of wiresharks *capture filter* and *display filter*.
Nevertheless, I am interested why I cannot disable NTP using `sudo timedatectl set-ntp off`?

---

**EDIT:**
I don't have chrony installed:

```
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ apt policy chrony | grep Installed
  Installed: (none)
```

Screenshot of wireshark capture:
[image: NTP_Wireshark_Capture]

List of files opened by process of UDP port 123:

```
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo lsof -iUDP:123
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ntpd    716  ntp   16u  IPv6  19895      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
ntpd    716  ntp   17u  IPv4  19900      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
ntpd    716  ntp   18u  IPv4  19904      0t0  UDP localhost:ntp 
ntpd    716  ntp   19u  IPv6  19906      0t0  UDP ip6-localhost:ntp 
ntpd    716  ntp   23u  IPv4  22229      0t0  UDP VirtualBox:ntp 
ntpd    716  ntp   24u  IPv6  22232      0t0  UDP VirtualBox:ntp
```

Comment: running chrony?

Comment: `timedatectl set-ntp` controls `systemd-timesyncd.service`, but that is not the only possible way to synchronize the system clock. There is `chrony` mentioned by Rui F Ribeiro, and the classic `ntpd`. There may be others. The NTP protocol uses UDP in port 123: `sudo lsof -i udp:123` should tell you which process is using that port on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I discovered the problem.
Additionally to 
`sudo timedatectl set-ntp off`,
I also had to execute the command 
`sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop`. 
After doing so, `sudo lsof -iUDP:123` 
shows me no more UDP-port-123 processes which were active before.
And wireshark does not capture any NTP traffic anymore.

```
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/ntp status | grep "Active:"
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-04-16 14:58:03 CEST; 5s ago
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
[ ok ] Stopping ntp (via systemctl): ntp.service.
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/ntp status | grep "Active:"
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-04-16 14:58:14 CEST; 3s ago
yuza@VirtualBox:~$ sudo lsof -iUDP:123
yuza@VirtualBox:~$
```

Thanks to [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) for the hint!